# Rebuttals in argumentative writing

Tags: academic-writing, essay

I am writing an argumentative essay and it goes along the following lines...

- Advantage 1; rebuttal 1
- Advantage 2; rebuttal 2
- Disadvantages

Would it be better to address the rebuttals in the disadvantages paragraph altogether, or should I tackle each point right after. 
For the former, it seems like it's more organised, because I'm not jumping from advantages to disadvantages, then back to advantages again. However, for the latter, it reminds the reader the point I was making instead of going back to check what points I have made.

Would be grateful for any advice!

P.S. I am new to this forum, so I'm not sure whether this content befits "writing".

Comment: I can't really answer this question, although it certainly is about writing and seems on-topic to me, so I don't think you need to worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the description of an argument and its rebuttal need more than one paragraph. Whole books have been written arguing one single point.

Usually when you write you create a new paragraph when you open up a new topic, discuss a different aspect of a previous topic, take an argumentative detour, and so on. An experienced writer will "feel" a paragraph break in the same way they feel a sentence break.

So don't overthink it and just write. Create a new paragraph whenever you feel that you have "said something" and want to say something else. Sort of like drawing a breath and gathering your thoughts when you speak.

---

I may be mistaken, but your questions makes me think that maybe you have been asked to write an essay for school and are now struggling with understanding what is expected of you.

A common problem with students I see is that most of them have never read an essay in their lives and don't really know what to do. You can compare this to someone who has never seen another person swim or ride a bike and is told to get in the water and "swim" or use that metal contraption to "ride". Most people wouldn't know what to do.

In the same way you need to have read many examples of what you want to write to form an understanding of the specific form. So often the best recommendation in the case of question like yours is to read a couple of essays, because very likely you will know how paragraphs work from having seen a few.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the decision is stylistic.  Sometimes you would want to present a proposed "advantage" and then push back against it, but often, that approach isn't the most helpful.

The question then is "what exactly are you trying to argue against?"  The answer to this will help you to organize your essay.  If you are working in a field that is unfamiliar to you, consider reviewing the structure of some essays arguing against an issue, and structure similarly.  If not, consider using a structure seen in the field.

However, if you're still at a loss, I've found the following *base* structure useful.

- Describe overall what you're arguing against.
- For each point you are rebutting:

  - Describe in greater depth
  - Rebut